# Le concept de Dualité fait référence à 2, à quel concept correspond alors 3?

Tags: vocabulaire, nombres

**Binaire** fait référence au nombre **2**, de même que **ternaire** pour le nombre **3**.

J'aimerais savoir si le mot décrivant un concept correspondant au nombre **3** de la même manière que **dualité** existe.

Comment: Ça marche aussi avec duo et trio.

Comment: Ce ne serait pas trinité ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Une petite recherche web indique que [*ternarité*](http://hm.coherences.com/BLOG-HM/2012/06/18/lunite-de-lhomme/) est apparemment un usage réel en philosophie.

Comment: Sans conteste *ternarité* est fort usitéé dans le domaine de la philosophie mais je m'attends également à des éléments de réponses relevant des mathématiques et/ou physique.

Answer (score 2):

Dans un contexte mathématique, il semblerait que le mot « trialité » soit utilisé.

Je dois avouer que je ne l'ai jamais vu auparavant, mais ce n'est pas mon domaine…

Un exemple trouvé sur internet : http://www.math.ethz.ch/~knus/talks/fri_mod.pdf

Ce mot n'existe cependant pas dans le dictionnaire du CNRTL.